# How to convert arabic .pdf or .rtf to .html or .txt using PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, rtf, doc

I have arabic pdf and rtf files
I need a tool or a class to convert it to html file or txt file or even doc file
Can any one help please?

Comment: SO is for questions about programming. Questions like "Is there a tool for X" are better asked on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

If you want convert your PDF to txt,doc & ... use this [site](http://pdftotext.com/fr/).

I hope it could help.